# retrieve the value selected in optionset field and display ita value in a text field

Tags: c#, plugins, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Could any one please help me in displaying an optionset field value in a text field..? I want to retrieve the value selected in optionset and display the same in a text field using plugin.. Iam writing this plugin on "update" of "case' entity...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For getting the option set value:

```
int value = ((OptionSetValue)entity["yourattributename"]).Value;
```

For getting the text:

```
String text = entity.FormattedValues["yourattributename"].ToString();
```

In the above code entity is the Entity object from which the optionset value/text to be retrieved. Please replace the attribute name with your case.

Comment: Initially it was like ***entity.GetFormattedAttributeValue("attributename");***

Now a days it is ***entity.FormattedValues["attributename"];***

Answer (score 4):

You should put this logic in the pre-update (and maybe pre-create) steps.  Retrieve the case from the Target parameter, get the display value of the option set field (there are several ways to do this, I like using the FormattedValues attribute), and set the text field to be this value.

```
entity["new_textfield"] = entity.FormattedValues["new_optionset"];
```

Comment: Worked great for me. Tx :)